# Join multiple "exec" as one output SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I'm tring to get multiple results from a dynamic exec to be columns of a table in a single output using SQL Server, right now the exec gives me multiple outputs as different temporal tables.

Is there a way to merge them together and get a single output?

This is my code:

```
Declare @status nvarchar(255)
Declare POINTER cursor global for select distinct status from intermedio
open POINTER
fetch NEXT from POINTER into @status
while (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
begin
exec('select distinct(
Select COUNT(*) from (
SELECT DISTINCT PKN
FROM INTERMEDIO
WHERE PIECE IN ('+'''+891''','''+75'''+') and ESTATUS = '''+@status+'''
group by PKN
having count(*)=2
) ser) as '+@status);
fetch next from POINTER into @status
end;
close POINTER;
DEALLOCATE POINTER;
```

Edit: Tried to explain myself better, once again excuse my poor english.
My table has three columns

```
+-----------+-------+---------+
|    PKN    | PIECE | ESTATUS |
+-----------+-------+---------+
| Set_one   | +891  | A1      |
| Set_one   | +75   | A1      |
| Set_one   | +45   | A1      |
| Set_two   | +891  | A3      |
| Set_two   | +75   | A3      |
| Set_three | +700  | B1      |
+-----------+-------+---------+
```

I'm trying to get the count of the PKNs that have both (+891, +75) and count how many exist under ESTATUS

The output I'm expecting is something like:

```
+----+----+----+
| A1 | A3 | B1 |
+----+----+----+
|  1 |  1 |  0 |
+----+----+----+
```

But it gives me the rows on different tables.

The reason I'm doing it like this is because the table can have many different ESTATUS at any time, and many different pieces on different PKN, the result will change constantly and the table generated will be different each time I execute the query.
I'm sorry if the question isn't clear, as english is not my first language.

Comment: Hello, you should add table structure, data sample and expected results.

Comment: I almost 100% sure that cursor in unnecessary. What you do is basically get values multiple times using loop and now you want to merge them back into one table. Of course you could use `INSERT INTO EXEC...` but you could use simple `INSERT INTO SELECT`.

Comment: I've edited the question to add table structure and expected results, thanks Horaciux

Comment: I noticed i had an extra comma in my code below @Richard. Let me know if the edit worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a dynamic pivot and a conditional aggregation. Here's an example.

```
create table #tempTable (PKN varchar(64), PIECE varchar(64), ESTATUS varchar(2))

insert into #tempTable
values
('Set_one','+891','A1'),     
('Set_one','+75','A1'),     
('Set_one','+45','A1'),     
('Set_two','+891','A3'),     
('Set_two','+75','A3'),      
('Set_three','+700','B1')    

select
    ESTATUS
     --here is the conditional aggregation
    ,floor(count(case when PIECE = '+891' or PIECE = '+75' then PKN end)/2) as CT
into #staging
from
    #tempTable
group by ESTATUS

DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(ESTATUS)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ESTATUS FROM #staging) AS ESTATUS

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #staging
    PIVOT(Sum(CT) 
          FOR ESTATUS IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery

drop table #tempTable
drop table #staging
```

**RETURNS**

```
+----+----+----+
| A1 | A3 | B1 |
+----+----+----+
|  1 |  1 |  0 |
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: This got me closer to the answer than I was before, I managed to do it using something similar to your code, the difference was that I needed to check if the PKN was repeated on the table with both pieces, and if it appeared with only one or the other, it didn't count.
All in all you helped me a lot, thanks.

Comment: glad to help @Richard